# What functions satisfy $x f(x) = f(x^{-1})$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

I would like to find functions that satisfy the relation $x f(x) = f(x^{-1})$.

So far I found $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, and $f(x)=\big|\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\big|$.

I'm mostly interested in smooth functions in $(0,\infty)$ (e.g. like the first one I mentioned, not the second one).

Is there a systematic way of finding such functions? If not, then are there any other functions that satisfy the aforementioned relation?

Comment: @eyeballfrog, I moved this to an asnwer.

Answer (score 4):

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be any even function and then set

$$f(x)=\frac{g(\log x)}{\sqrt{x}}. $$

Then $f : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the property. The converse is also true, and both claims can be easily verified. Here are some examples:

**Example 1.** Let $g(x) = 1$, then $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

**Example 2.** Let $g(x) = |x|$, then $f(x) = \left| \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}} \right| $.

**Example 3.** Consider $f(x) = (1 - x^{-1/2})^2$. This function clearly solves the functional equation. Then $g$ corresponding to the construction is $g(x) = (e^{x/4}-e^{-x/4})^2$, which is clearly even.

Answer (score 3):

Set $g(x) = \sqrt{x} f(x)$

Then we get $g(x) = g\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

This should allow you to pick any values on $(0,1)$ (with $g(1) = 1$) to try and get the properties you desire.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial answer is $f(x) = 0$